# Why is `cmd /C` living after it did its job?

Tags: windows-7, windows

My question is why does "cmd" exist (idle) in my process after i update my exe?

In my code i run this code to update myself and launch

```
var args = string.Format(@"/C ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 & move /Y ""{0}"" ""{1}"" & ""{1}"" {2}", updateFn, fn, exeargs);
new Process() { StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd", args) { CreateNoWindow = true, UseShellExecute = false } }.Start();
Environment.Exit(0);
```

The idea is i exit right away and have ping stall for 3seconds before trying to replace my current exe with my updated exe. Then i launch with the necessary args

The full arg for cmd looks like this

> /C ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 & move /Y "c:\path\update" "c:\path\my.exe" & "c:\path\my.exe" exeargs

Everything works fine however i see cmd in the taskmanager (looks to be idle) after my process is launched and correctly working. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last part of your argument is `& "c:\path\my.exe" exeargs` which causes the command-interpreter to wait for `my.exe` to finish running before it exits and obviously `my.exe` is not a program that runs and exists on its own; it is staying active.

You can use `start my.exe` to have the command-interpreter launch `my.exe` and continue on without waiting for it.

Comment: oh yeah... durr >_<